# consuming SAML assertion

Tags: web-services, soap, saml

I'm trying to use a soap service that requires authentication passing him a SAML assertion, for some reason i'm doing it manually (please don't start suggesting "use this or that library", i need to understand at least theoretically what must be done.

So far I did:

- ask the issuer a SAML assertion passing it username and password (all works, i receive a SAML assertion)
- prepared the soap message that will be sent using an http client, and message is correct and works excluding the authentication.
- I insert in the soap message the exact assertion text received and the message i send to the WS is something like:

---

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <soapenv:Header>
       <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-    wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
          <saml:Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" AssertionID="..../ds:Signature></Assertion>  
       </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header> 
<soapenv:Body>....
```

but the result is an error in response:

wsse:InvalidSecurity, Missing wsse:Security header in request

Why it happens? it is wrong to directly reuse the "< saml:Assertion" received? Should I process and re-sign it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing a namespace reference!

it was missing in the security block the text

```
 xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/"
```

to enable the use in the assertion of xenc blocks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: actually it answer to the question however i edit it to make more understandable, it's all about the fact in the inner xml was used some tag referencing namespaces not directly defined.